# Have git rerere automatically mark files as resolved?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, git-rerere

I'm using git rerere, and it is useful, but there is one problem: When it automatically resolves a file, it does not mark it as resolved (eg with git add). So if I run 'git mergetool', it opens up the file as if it still has all the conflicts in it.

So far, I've made a small shell script which I can call, which scans all files marked as conflicted for conflict markers (eg `>>>>>>>`), and calls git-add on them if they have none.

Is there a better way of doing this? Some flag to git rerere I missed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe a [`git config`](http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/ftp/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) setting can help:

```
rerere.autoupdate
```

> When set to true, [`git-rerere`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html) updates the index with the resulting contents after it cleanly resolves conflicts using previously recorded resolution.
> Defaults to false.

Note: since Git1.7.0,

> "`git rerere`" had `rerere.autoupdate` configuration but there was no way to countermand it from the command line;
> `--no-rerere-autoupdate` option given to "`merge`", "`revert`", etc. fixes this.

---

Git 2.38 (Q3 2022) updates documentation on the "`--[no-]rerere-autoupdate`" option.

See [commit cb54fc9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb54fc93e4627d9496fff1c4ba18b1705802d069) (03 Aug 2022), and [commit 0dbc715](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dbc715ae0ccf0991d032173d86890a90bf94814) (15 Jul 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3adacc2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3adacc2817bf4644928b9430c7c6ed1ca2ef2655), 14 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb54fc93e4627d9496fff1c4ba18b1705802d069): clarify rerere-autoupdate

> The "`--[no-]rerere-autoupdate`" option controls what happens *after* the rerere mechanism kicks in to reuse recorded resolutions and does not prevent from the rerere mechanism to trigger in the first place.
>
> It is unclear in the current text if "`--no-rerere-autoupdate`" stops the auto-resolution.
> Rewrite the sentence to clarify.

`rerere-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cb54fc93e4627d9496fff1c4ba18b1705802d069/Documentation/rerere-options.txt#L3-L9):

> After the rerere mechanism reuses a recorded resolution on
> the current conflict to update the files in the working
> tree, allow it to also update the index with the result of
> resolution.
>
> `--no-rerere-autoupdate` is a good way to
> double-check what `rerere` did and catch potential
> mismerges, before committing the result to the index with a
> separate `git add`.

Comment: Ah, there was my problem. I was looking in the git-rerere page for help, which is quite sparse. Didn't think to grep through other git man pages to see if they also had rerere info in them!